# Unable to Load json using python scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy, response

I am trying to load json using scrapy but i am getting this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 10718 (char 10717)
```

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json


class CodeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'trip'
    allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g155019-d5058155-Reviews-The_Tilted_Dog_Pub_Kitchen-Toronto_Ontario.html']
    def start_requests(self):
        for a in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = a,callback= self.parse_data)


    def parse_data(self, response):
        el = (response.xpath('//div[@id="taplc_footer_js_globals_0"]/following::script[1]/text()').get()).split('"responses":')[1]
        data = json.loads(el)
```

The goal is to get the data from json. Waiting for your kind answer

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple jsons in `el`. You can paste the response [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) and check why you are getting an output while parsing the json.

You will need to split the `el` into parts, you can try something like `json.loads(el.split('},"page"')[0])` to get the first json object and so on.